# How can I get parent branch detail in Microsoft VSTS API when I have only Pull request I'd

Tags: git, azure-devops-rest-api, hotfix

I am working on patch release. I am getting change list from vsts using Microsoft VSTS API. I have 3 branches like A -> B -> C. 
A is base branch and b is created sub branch from A and c is created sub branch from B. So whatever changes I made in A and B that will be in C branch as well as C branch change. Now I have one pull request I'd which is targeted to the C branch. I am able to get all commits of C branch using pull request I'd. But I want to get parent class detail of C and then A. I tried but there is nothing I found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Through [Get Pull Request By Id](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/pull%20requests/get%20pull%20request%20by%20id?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) rest api, you can get the `repository id`, `sourceRefName`, `targetRefName` from the response body.

[image]

[image]

Then you can call [Get Commits Batch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/commits/get%20commits%20batch?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1#examples) rest api through the `repository id` and `sourceRefName` parameters to get all the commits of the parent branch.

```
POST https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryId}/commitsbatch?api-version=5.1
```

Sample request body:

```
{
  "itemVersion": {
    "versionType": "branch",
    "version": "dev"
  }
}
```

Sample response:

```
{
    "count": 32,
    "value": [
        {
            "commitId": "bbcb0ee346961422c686fd4d3b2f63f74dffa1e3",
            "author": {
                "name": "hughl01",
                "email": "xxx@hotmail.com",
                "date": "2020-05-20T01:44:05Z"
            },
            "committer": {
                "name": "hughl01",
                "email": "xxx@hotmail.com",
                "date": "2020-05-20T01:44:05Z"
            },
            "comment": "Deleted NEW",
            "changeCounts": {
                "Add": 0,
                "Edit": 0,
                "Delete": 2
            },
            "url": "https://dev.azure.com/xx/59b994e8-4a77-46a1-8b5d-xx/_apis/git/repositories/da09f0c6-1999-45b5-bb93-faa59f69fa24/commits/bbcb0ee346961422c686fd4d3b2f63f74dffxx",
            "remoteUrl": "https://dev.azure.com/xx/xx/_git/forTest/commit/bbcb0ee346961422c686fd4d3b2f63f74dfxx"
        },
 ...
}
```

Comment: This will work if my pull request merge the changes in to parent branch. I have query when C is child of B and B is child of A. But I merged PR in C branch which is C->TaskBranch Then My Pull request will show SourceRef = "refs/Head/TaskBranch" and TargetRef="refs/Head/C". And also these changes I am not going merge in B branch which is parent of C. In this case wont get link between B and C branch. Any suggestion would be appreciate.